# What does Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null mean?

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a N x N matrix that will print with 0's and 1's. It shows no errors in the code, but when I run my code I get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

I have no idea how to fix it.

```
public class LargestRowColumn {

    public static void printMatrix (int n){

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                System.out.println((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ " ");
            }

            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        String Matrix = null;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(Matrix);

        System.out.print(n);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It means you are trying to parse `null` as an int :

```
String Matrix = null;
int n = Integer.parseInt(Matrix);
```

You probably want to get some input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to convert `null` to integer

```
String Matrix = null;
Integer.parseInt(Matrix); // here is exception
```

if you want input from user then do like this:

```
int matrix=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
printMatrix(matrix); // print matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get input from the user, Scanner Class is the best way. To use it, write code like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;             //since JAVA SE 7

public class AnyClass{

   public static void main(String[] a){ 
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
                        //telling Scanner Class to proceed with input Stream

   System.out.println("Enter a number");
   int n = scan.nextInt();             //getting a number from the user

   }
}
```

And for writing good code, try to use **try** and **catch** blocks for catching Exception(s).

You can enclose your code present in main() method in this example in try block followed by one or more catch block for catching the Exception and to deal with it.